# electron-forge won't let me use NSIS

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to make an application with a customizable installer through NSIS, but electron-forge always reverts to Squirrel.Windows.

Comment: Please include some more details. Any error message? Your configuration? The platform you're running on?

Comment: There was no error message, i don't know what you mean by configuration, and I'm on windows.

Comment: Surely Electron-Forge has some sort of configuration options? Otherwise why would you expect NSIS instead of Squirrel?

Comment: No, the quickstart guide says so

Comment: The quickstart guide isn't the entirety of the documentation; it's just the quickstart guide. You need to help people to help you.